# Problems catching "Tap and hold" touch event on QPushButton in QT

Tags: c++, qt, windows-8, touch, multi-touch

I have a `QPushButton` where I have connected to the `pressed()` signal, and set `autoRepeat=true`.

The button updates a number when clicked (with a mouse), and when you click and hold it repeats.

This works fine with a mouse. Single click steps once, click and hold repeats it. Simple tap works fine using the touch screen, but it does not repeat on "tap and hold".

I have tried disabling the "tap and hold to right click" setting in Windows 8, but that did not help. It only prevents the right click from happening.

If I tap QPushButton and move the finger away from the button (while still holding), and then move the finger back into the QPushButton works, the pressed() event will start autoRepeating.

**MyPanel.ui:**

```
<widget class="QPushButton" name="UpButton">
  <property name="text">
    <string/>
  </property>
  <property name="autoRepeat">
    <bool>true</bool>
  </property>
</widget>

<connection>
  <sender>UpButton</sender>
  <signal>pressed()</signal>
  <receiver>my_panel</receiver>
  <slot>UpAction()</slot>
  <hints>
    <hint type="sourcelabel">
      <x>40</x>
      <y>261</y>
    </hint>
    <hint type="destinationlabel">
      <x>121</x>
      <y>37</y>
    </hint>
  </hints>
</connection>
```

**MyPanel.cpp:**

```
void MyPanel::UpAction()
{
    myNumber += 1;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using the `Qt::TapAndHoldGesture`?

Answer (score 0):

Do not forget to take a look at official documentation -- [Gestures Programming](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/gestures-overview.html). There you can find useful information about handling gestures.

You forgot to **grab** your gesture, by setting `grabGesture(Qt::TapAndHoldGesture);` on your `QPushButton`. When you enable this, your `QPushButton` starts to grab `TapAndHoldGesture`s through its `event`. So you need to have your button-class inherited from `QPushButton` with overrided `event` method. You can control whole process of gesture recognizing and handling now. Take a look at example [Image Gestures Example](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/gestures-imagegestures.html).